# Tabela do banco não atualiza

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6, sql-select, linq-to-entities

Tenho no meu banco algumas tabelas elas já contem dados guardados, mas não estou conseguindo atualizar esses dados.

Tenho o método abaixo que realiza a inserção de um novo item na tabela caso a tabela não possua o item, caso possua o os dados que estiverem na tabela devem ser atualizados.

A parte de inserção esta funcionando, o problema esta na atualização da tabela quando já tenho o item.
 Por exemplo quero comprar uma ação de uma determinada empresa. Quando não tenho ele funciona, mas se já tenho e quero adicionar mais, ele não esta atualizando.
 Ao invés disso esta inserindo mais um registro na tabela ao invés de atualizar os dados.

Já debuguei o código e percebi que ele verifica se já tenho aquela ação e pula direto para o bloco Else do código acima. quando busco os valores que tenho no banco percebi que no Select em Linq o obj.cpf e obj.codigo não apresentam valores para fazer a comparação, mas mesmo assim recebo os dados guardados no banco as atualizações dos valores são feitas e os métodos.

O método é esse:

```
 public void compraAcoes(string cepf, string codigo, int quantidade)
    {


        string cd = codigo;
        try
        {

            string cpf;
            BuscaNet busca = new BuscaNet();
            Cotacao objeto = new Cotacao();

            objeto = busca.buscaInformacao(codigo);
            cpf = cepf;
            string empresa = objeto.empresa;
            string tipo = objeto.tipo;
            DateTime data = Convert.ToDateTime(objeto.data);
            string hora = objeto.hora;
            double abertura = objeto.abertura;
            double maxima = objeto.maxima;
            double minima = objeto.minima;
            double media = objeto.media;
            double fechamento = objeto.fechamento;
            double fechamento_anterior = objeto.fechamento_anterior;
            Int32 volume = objeto.volume;
            Int32 volume_financeiro = objeto.volume_financeiro;
            Int32 negocio = objeto.negocio;
            double oferta_de_compra = objeto.oferta_de_compra;
            double oferta_de_venda = objeto.oferta_de_venda;
            Int32 quantidade_ofertada_compra = objeto.quantidade_ofertada_compra;
            Int32 quantidade_ofertada_venda = objeto.quantidade_fertada_venda;
            double variação = objeto.variacao;
            string status = objeto.status;
            string fase = objeto.fase;


            string cod = codigo;
            bancotccEntities bc = new bancotccEntities();
            acao ac = bc.acao.FirstOrDefault(obj => obj.cpf == cepf && obj.codigo == cod);
            // Verifica se o usuario possui a ação
            if (ac == null)
            { 
                // Insere a nova ação no banco
                double vatotal_acao = (quantidade * fechamento);
                double valor_investido = vatotal_acao + taxas;

                banco.inserirAcao(cepf, cod, empresa, tipo, data, hora, abertura, maxima, minima, media, fechamento, fechamento_anterior, volume, volume_financeiro, negocio,
                          oferta_de_compra, oferta_de_venda, quantidade_ofertada_compra, quantidade_ofertada_venda, variação, status, fase);

                banco.inserirCarteira(cepf, cod, fechamento, quantidade, vatotal_acao, valor_investido, valor_inicial);


            }
            else
            {
                //atualiza a ação no banco
                carteira ca = bc.carteira.FirstOrDefault(obj => obj.cpf == cepf && obj.codigo == cod);

               ca.qtdacao = ca.qtdacao + quantidade;
               ca.vtotalacao = ca.vtotalacao + quantidade * fechamento;
               ca.vinvestido = ca.vinvestido +ca.vtotalacao + taxas;
               ca.vinicial = ca.vinicial;

               int quant = Convert.ToInt32(ca.qtdacao);
               double valor_da_acao = fechamento;
               double valor_gasto = Convert.ToDouble(ca.vtotalacao);
               double valor_investido = Convert.ToDouble(ca.vinvestido);

                 banco.atualizaAcao(cepf, codigo, empresa, tipo, data, hora, abertura, maxima, minima, media, fechamento, fechamento_anterior,
                         volume, volume_financeiro, negocio, oferta_de_compra, oferta_de_venda, quantidade_ofertada_compra,
                         quantidade_ofertada_venda, variação, status, fase);

                 banco.atualizarCarteira(cepf, cod,valor_da_acao, quant, valor_gasto,valor_investido);

            }




        }
      /*  catch (Exception e)
        {

            throw new Exception(e.Message.ToString());
        }*/
        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

O método atualiza ação e esse:

```
 public void atualizaAcao(string cpf, string codigo, string empresa, string tipo, DateTime data, string hora, double abertura,
                                   double maxima, double minima, double media, double fechamento, double fechamento_anterior, int volume,
                                   int volume_financeiro, int negocio, double oferta_de_compra, double oferta_de_venda, int quantidade_ofertada_compra,
                                   int quantidade_fertada_venda, double variação, string status, string fase)
    {
        try
        {
            validaAtualizaAcao(cpf, codigo, empresa, tipo, data, hora, abertura, maxima, minima, media, fechamento, fechamento_anterior,
                              volume, volume_financeiro, negocio, oferta_de_compra, oferta_de_venda, quantidade_ofertada_compra,
                              quantidade_fertada_venda, variação, status, fase);
            bancotccEntities bco = new bancotccEntities();
            string codi = codigo;
            acao papel = bco.acao.FirstOrDefault(obj => obj.cpf == cpf && obj.codigo == codi);
            if (papel == null) { throw new Exception("Codigo não localizado, possivelmente você não possui esta ação!"); }
            papel.cpf = cpf;
            papel.codigo = codi;
            papel.empresa = empresa;
            papel.tipo = tipo;
            papel.data = Convert.ToDateTime(data);
            papel.hora = hora;
            papel.abertura = abertura;
            papel.maxima = maxima;
            papel.minima = minima;
            papel.medio = media;
            papel.fechamento = fechamento;
            papel.f_anterior = fechamento_anterior;
            papel.volume = volume;
            papel.v_financeiro = volume_financeiro;
            papel.negocio = negocio;
            papel.ofcompra = oferta_de_compra;
            papel.ofvenda = oferta_de_venda;
            papel.qtd_of__compra = quantidade_ofertada_compra;
            papel.qtd_of_venda = quantidade_fertada_venda;
            papel.variacao = Convert.ToString(variação);
            papel.status = Convert.ToInt32(status);
            papel.fase = fase;


            // Adiciona o objeto ao banco
            bco.acao.Add(papel);
           // bco.AddToacao(papel);

            //Salva as modificações no banco
            bco.SaveChanges();

           // SubmitChanges(); 
        }
       /* catch (Exception e)
        {

            throw new Exception(e.Message.ToString());
        }*/
        catch (DbEntityValidationException e) { foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors) { Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:", eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State); foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors) { Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"", ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage); } } throw; } 

    }
```

O método atualiza carteira é esse:

```
public void atualizarCarteira(string cpf, string codigo, double valor, int quant, double vtotal, double vinvestido)
    {
        try
        {
            validaAtualizarCarteira(cpf, codigo, valor, quant, vtotal, vinvestido);
            // instancia  o banco de dados
            bancotccEntities bco = new bancotccEntities();
            string cod = codigo;
            // busca na tabela carteira do banco uma ação correspondente ao código e atualiza-a 
            carteira crt = bco.carteira.FirstOrDefault(obj => obj.cpf == cpf && obj.codigo == cod);
            if (crt == null) { throw new Exception("Codigo não localizado, possivelmente você não possui esta ação!"); }
            crt.cpf = cpf;
            crt.codigo = codigo;
            crt.valoracao = valor;
            crt.qtdacao = crt.qtdacao + quant;
            crt.vtotalacao = crt.vtotalacao + vtotal;
            crt.vinvestido = crt.vinvestido + vinvestido;
            crt.vinicial = crt.vinicial;

            bco.carteira.Add(crt);
            bco.SaveChanges();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            throw new Exception(e.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Está errado.

Modifique seu código para o seguinte:

```
bco.Entry(papel).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
bco.SaveChanges();
```

O mesmo vale para `carteira`:

```
bco.Entry(crt).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
bco.SaveChanges();
```

`Add()` serve apenas para inclusão. Para atualização, é preciso marcar o objeto no contexto como modificado e depois invocar o método para salvar as modificações.

Comment: Ok cigano obrigado funcionou.